# Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503 Response appear after CORS call

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, heroku

**CORS setup with Spring MVC (JAVA APPLICATION)**

```
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"}, description = "CORS")
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

public void destroy() {}

}
```

I try to make a **POST** to my application and the post is running, but in the middle of the running, Y receive this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://finaldomain/start/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://originDomain/  header is present
>   on the requested resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 503.

My both applications are deployed in **Heroku** and the post is making with **Angular**.

**Heroku Log:**

> 2015-10-03T21:50:14.474181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/start/" host=finaldomain request_id=84f76fea-0226-43b0-898d-e753681d7622 fwd="190.1
>   95.196.252" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

***I investigate more and I learn that is a timeout of Heroku, anybody know how to change it?***

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*I Resolved this problem with a back proccess.*

Comment: Care to expand on that to help others?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

This will prevent Heroku from closing the connection. The Heroku request timeout is 30 seconds, and it will send a `Connection: close` header if it does not see the chunked header (this is allowed because it is a hop by hop header).